# TypeError: ´numpy.uint8´ object is not iterable`

Tags: python, python-2.7, colors

This code shall convert my RGB-image into Black/White and provide me the RGB-value -which should be (0, 0, 0) or (255, 255, 255).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

template = cv2.imread('C:\colorbars.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

gray = cv2.resize(gray,(640,480))
ret,gray = cv2.threshold(gray,120,255,0)
gray2 = gray.copy()
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape,np.uint8)

contours, hier = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    if 200<cv2.contourArea(cnt)<5000:
        cv2.drawContours(gray2,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),-1)
cv2.bitwise_not(gray2,gray2,mask)

y = 250
x = 200
r, g, b = gray2[y,x]

print r, g, b
```

It works if I check the RGB value of the colored image with the line `r, g, b = template[y,x]`; however as soon as I want to have the RGB value of the Black/White image, following error message appears:

`File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\myprogram.py", Line 22, in <module>
r, g, b = gray2[y,x]
TypeError: ´numpy.uint8´ object is not iterable`

I assume it means that there are not enough objects in the array and I assume that the problem lies somewhere in the conversion from color to B/W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "gray" variable is a 2D matrix (because of the grayscale), so when you ask for gray2[x,y], it returns a single unsigned integer in 8 bit (np.unint8) corresponding to the grayscale value of the [x,y] pixel.

When you do : r,g,b =gray2[x,y], you expect 3 values (r, g, b), but it returns only 1 so you get an error.

You should precise what you are trying to do, as asking for the RGB values of a grayscale image makes no sense.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was taking the part of the code from some other example, where it said that it is the best first to grayscale the image and then convert it into B/W. Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do and I think there is a confusion :
RGB : is a color image, stored as a 3D matrix (one Red, one Green, One Blue)
Grayscale is not a color image, but provide a value (typically between 0 and 255 for 8 bits).
B/W is usually binarized images, where values are either 0 or 1.
What kind of result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I see, looks like I´m mixing something up. I want to still have the 3D-matrix (as I think it is the easiest way) and check the RGB value of the image. If it is (0, 0, 0) it shall do no action, if it is (255, 255, 255) I want to have a notification. Does this make it a bit clearer?

Comment: What is the final goal of your code? When you use "ret,gray = cv2.threshold(gray,120,255,0)", your gray variable is a binarized image, and you just have to look for gray[x,y] ==255. I think it's easier this way, rather than looking for RGB values in a 3D matrix

Comment: It depends on your original image. What happens here is that you transform your RGB (colored) image into a grayscale image (with values between 0 and 255), and then you binarize this image with a threshold set to 120, meaning all values >120 will now have the value 255 and all values <120 will have the value 0. If your RGB image is very dark, grayscale image can be entirely under 120, and then be entirely black (=0) when you binarize. Check gray.max() before the threshold .

Comment: I see your point. The problem is that I need some kind of logarithm that converts the rgb into B/W, now it needs to be tested. Will let you the outcome. Besides: the `print gray.max()` gave out `255`, so that should be fine, right? Thanks for all your effort so far!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use just ONE channel to get the result instead of 3 channels,
for example: `r = gray2[x,y]`